# Getting this error #1064

Tags: php

When I'm inserting my table empinfo

Query for Insert table

```
$sql="INSERT INTO empinfo(EmpName,Add,MobileNo)values('$EmpName','$Add','$MobileNo')";
```

I get the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Add,MobileNo)values('jaimin','Baroda','123')' at line 1
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien He is using that, he put the error message in the quesiton.

Comment: @Barmar Aah sorry I missed that \` <-

Answer (score 1):

`Add` is a [reserved word within MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). If you want to use it as an identifier, then surround it with backticks (as you always should do with identifiers):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO empinfo(`EmpName`,`Add`,`MobileNo`)values('$EmpName','$Add','$MobileNo')";
```

Answer (score 1):

`Add` is a reserved word. If you want to use it as a column name, you have to put it in backticks:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO empinfo(EmpName,`Add`,MobileNo)values('$EmpName','$Add','$MobileNo')";
```